# Finding files that have been modified using a script?

Tags: scripting, find

I need to find files in a given directory that have been modified in the last N days, where N is the second argument of the script. Basically, I need to give the command with 2 numbers (arguments) and run a script which would do this.

Is this line of code right in order to find the files?

```
find . -type f -mtime $2 -exec ls -l {} \;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of. You don't need `-exec ls -l {} \;`, the `find` command already lists the files. If you want to list them with more details, you can use `find -ls`. There's nothing wrong with `-exec ls ...` either, it's fine if you prefer that, just not needed.

The `-mtime N` will find files that were modified *exactly* N days ago. The details are in `man find`:

```
  +n     for greater than n,

  -n     for less than n,

   n      for exactly n.
```

So, to find the files modified in the last 2 days, you would run

```
find /target/path -mtime -2 -ls
```

Note that `find .` will search in the current directory. To search in a specific directory, use a path like `find /path/to/dir`. If the 1st argument is the target directory, use (remember to always quote your variables):

```
find "$1" -mtime -"$2" -ls
```

Also, note that `-mtime` only deals with 24 hour periods, "days". You'll need to take that into account when writing your command. As explained in `man find` (this is for `-atime` but the same applies to `-mtime`):

> File was last accessed n*24 hours ago.  When  find  figures  out
>    how  many  24-hour  periods  ago the file was last accessed, **any
>    fractional part is ignored, so to match -atime +1, a file has to
>    have been accessed at least two days ago**.